# django query for date time

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a one major issue regarding my django query.
my query is:-

```
query=AllTime.objects.values('startdate').order_by('timeid').annotate(spent=Sum('spent')).filter(project_id=project_id,startdate__range=(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=15),datetime.datetime.now()))
```

The query give me a below output:-

```
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-12",
    "spent": 84
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-13",
    "spent": 7
},
{

    "startdate": "2015-01-19",
    "spent": 32
}
```

The problem is that i am getting those dates which is already in my table.
but i want the output like this

```
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-12",
    "spent": 84
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-13",
    "spent": 7
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-14",
    "spent": 0
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-15",
    "spent": 0
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-16",
    "spent": 0
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-17",
    "spent": 0
},
{
    "startdate": "2015-01-18",
    "spent": 0
},
{

    "startdate": "2015-01-19",
    "spent": 32
}
```

How can I get the above output for django query???

Comment: If the rows are not in the table, how do you expect them to be in your result set?

Comment: that is the main challenge for this query....

Answer (score 0):

You can't create such query.  The only way is to create a list with the values for all required dates:

```
days_to_show = 15
start_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_show)

query = AllTime.objects.values('startdate').order_by('timeid') \
               .annotate(spent=Sum('spent')) \
               .filter(project_id=project_id,
                       startdate__range=(start_date, datetime.datetime.now()))

spent_dict = dict((d['startdate'], d['spent']) for d in query)

date_list = [(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=day)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                                 for day in range(0, days_to_show)]
spent_list = [{'startdate': date, "spent": spent_dict.get(date, 0)}
                                 for date in date_list]
```

Comment: What is the content of `spent_dict`? What type of `AllTime.startdate`? DateField?

Comment: content of spent_dict is:-{u'2015-01-19': 32.0, u'2015-01-12': 84.0, u'2015-01-13': 7.0, u'2015-01-22': 21.0} and AllTime.startdate is string field not DateField

Comment: Oh, ok. I added `strftime` call to the generation of `date_list`.

Comment: What do you mean? `spent_list` is the exactly the same list of dicts as you show in the question.

Comment: That value of "spent":?? is not correct.always return 0.

Comment: and spent_dict returns:-{u'2015-01-19': 32.0, u'2015-01-12': 84.0, u'2015-01-13': 7.0, u'2015-01-22': 21.0} and spent_list returns:-{'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 7), 'spent': 0}, {'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 8), 'spent': 0}, {'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 9), 'spent': 0}, {'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 10), 'spent': 0}, {'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 11), 'spent': 0}, {'startdate': datetime.date(2015, 1, 12)

Comment: You forgot to change generation of the `date_list`.  Note the `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` call.